# How do you create a "nested" bar graph?

Tags: r, graph

The last image in [this blog post](http://saaientist.blogspot.com/2011/09/visualize-this-by-nathan-yau-arrived.html).

I have tried searching "nested bar graph" and "hierarchical bar graph", but they may not be the word for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ggplot` and create separate layers:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
stupid <- data.frame(
    group= LETTERS[1:5],
    men = sample(1:10, 5),
    women = sample(1:10, 5) 
)

# Melt the data and calculate totals
mstupid <- melt(stupid, id.vars="group")
stupidTotal <- ddply(mstupid, .(group), summarize, value=sum(value))

ggplot() +
    geom_bar(data=stupidTotal, aes(x=group, y=value), fill="grey50") +
    geom_bar(data=mstupid, aes(x=group, y=value, fill=variable), 
             stat="identity", position="dodge") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look for 'barNest' in package `plotrix`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_bar(data=stupidTotal, aes(x=group, y=value, fill="grey50"), stat="identity") +
    geom_bar(data=mstupid, aes(x=group, y=value, fill=variable), 
             stat="identity", position="dodge") +
    theme_bw()
```